# Add a custom property to GridFS Meteor FS file during upload

Tags: javascript, meteor, metadata, gridfs

I'm currently creating a file upload and display feature for a web app.

I need to add a custom property (e.g accountID) so that I can later display only the images belonging to a specific account.

I'm using cfs:standard-packages with gridfs to upload/store my images.

I believe I need to add a beforeWrite function to the FS.Store but am unsure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to immediately update the inserted object as follows:

```
var fileId = MyFiles.insert(file);
MyFiles.update({ _id: fileId },{ $set: { accountId: myAccountId }});
```

Note that the actual upload of the file object to the store will be asynchronous but you'll get the `_id` back synchronously and immediately.

Comment: But is this efficient on Scale? If you have 100k> users and you update on each insert as well, is that a big thing?

Comment: It's just like updating any other collection document. It really shouldn't be a big deal, especially compared to other issues you'll eventually encounter. If you read about scaling scaling Meteor updating a collection like this won't even get a mention.